# Using LIKE '%string%' search in SAS SQL and getting an error

Tags: sql, sas

Have a very unusual problem. I have a SAS program that runs some SQL code.

this is the part of the code:

```
NOT LIKE '%CLOSE%'
```

When I run my program from SAS Enterprise Guide, it works, but when I run my program `sas /path/program.sas` in linux, I am getting this error:

`ERROR: Macro keyword CLOSE is not yet implemented.`

Another error for SQL code:

```
NOT LIKE ('%return%')
```

And getting: `ERROR: The %RETURN statement is not valid in open code.`

I am wondering if there is a work around?

Comment: weird, I doubt its the issue but have you tried double quotes instead of single? `"` vs `'`?  Or maybe the % needs to be escaped?

Comment: maybe because these are `reserved` keywords.

Comment: This is either a sign of a problem in the code (as my answer) or something weird with the SAS macro parser.  `'` is correct (not `"`), and they should be legal in that context (even as reserved words).

Comment: Can you create a dummy dataset to test the statement against.  And try submitting the program with nothing but that statement?  Also, how are you getting your code from EG to Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to make it work, I did this type of 'work-around':

```
/* NOT LIKE '%CLOSE%' */
NOT LIKE '%'||'CLOSE'||'%'

/* NOT LIKE ('%return%') */
NOT LIKE ('%'||'return'||'%')
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: see if you're getting truncated lines, or otherwise have unbalanced quotations.  If your `LRECL` system option is not long enough, you might have truncation occurring.  You should get a warning about this, but perhaps you didn't notice.

That may lead to you having an unbalanced quote, which means you have (earlier)

```
'LONG STRING THAT IS BEING TRUNCATED'
... more code ...
like '%return%';
```

becoming

```
'LONG STRING THAT IS BEING TRUNC
... more code ...
like '%return%';
```

which means the first `'` on the third line becomes the closing quote for the above string, and then `%return` is in open code.

You may get a warning, either about the truncation, or the `QUOTELENMAX` warning ("WARNING: String exeeds 255 characters" or somesuch).

You also should check to see if you have any comments (perhaps ones you wouldn't normally  include in the execution) with single quotes in them.  For example:

```
*don't do this;
```

If that were in a macro, the SAS macro parser (in EG, DM, or batch) would parse this as a quote, and cause things to fail after it.  (Thanks @Robert Pendridge for reminding me of this.)

---

Another thing you should do is test a simple test case - see if this occurs in the simple case, and if it doesn't, then simplify your real case until it's similar to the test case.

A good test case:

```
%macro test;
proc sql;
  select * from sashelp.class
  where name like '%return%';
quit;
%mend test;
%test;
```

Of course, no rows should be selected, but no error should occur.  Then change this as little as possible, a bit at a time, until you get your error; then you can see the problem.

Comment: Some more checks.... If being submitted in batch mode (at least in Windows), having any single line within a %macro definition longer than ?150ish? characters can be truncated and cause issues (even without quotes).  Best just to keep them pretty short.  Finally, as an extreme check, try removing comments.  I've had very rare issues where header comments were screwing up the parser.

Comment: The SAS macro parser will absolutely screw up when you have a comment with a single quote in it - such as `*don't do this;` - but it should also do the same in EG, of course.

Comment: Yup.  This was over 10 years ago that I first encountered it but I'm thinking that it was from `/* */` style comments as it took me a whole day to figure out and I do remember being incredulous when I found it.  Can't be a 100% sure though. My memory is pretty shoddy at the best of times...

Comment: In `/* */` style comments it won't be parsed, fortunately, though that could be a newer thing.  (At least in 9.3 it won't be.)

Comment: Still unable to figure it out... The 'worst part' is that it is working as expected from SAS Enterprise Guide!

Comment: @Andrew Can you repeat the issue with a very simple piece of code, perhaps on a different dataset such as `sashelp.class`?  Could it be the way you're copying code from EG over to Linux?  Perhaps there's some funky invisible character messing up your code that isn't visible in your editor.  Does removing the like statement fix it?  What if you re-type that line of code manually?

Comment: @RobertPenridge Exactly what I was thinking at the same time... Andrew, you should see if the test case works.  If it also fails, then definitely contact SAS Tech Support, maybe you have a bug in the Linux version.